# Values from Select option are not printed when I click on Print button

Tags: javascript, html

I have coded a javascript button to print all HTML from my page. When I click on the same, all prints fine except the values of `option` on select. Below is the code snippet.

**Live demo of the issue:**

https://codepen.io/T9-T9/pen/VwLKbOv

So on the demo, if you update the options from "a" to "b" or other and click on "Print Result", it will still print the default "a" and not what you select. Code snippet as below.

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="printcontent">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
            <h4>Title here</h4>
                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label class='life_area'>01</label>
                        <select id='01'>
                          <option value="1">a</option>
                          <option value="2">b</option>
                          <option value="3">c</option>
                          <option value="4">d</option>
                        </select>
                        <label class='life_area'>02</label>
                        <select id='02'>
                          <option value="1">a</option>
                          <option value="2">b</option>
                          <option value="3">c</option>
                          <option value="4">d</option>
                        </select>
                    </fieldset> 
                </form>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="print-content">
         <form>
          <input type="button" class="print-result" onClick="PrintElem('print-content')" value="print result"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
function PrintElem(elem)
        {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=800,width=2200');

            mywindow.document.write('<html><head>');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('printcontent').innerHTML);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.document.close(); 
            mywindow.focus();       

            setTimeout(function () {
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
            }, 1000)
            return true;
        }
```

I made multiple updates, but cannot fix this part.

Answer (score 2):

The `innerHTML` of an element will *only* retrieve the HTML markup - it won't retrieve state of an element which may not be in the HTML. For example, when a select changes, that doesn't change the HTML markup. (similarly, neither does putting text into an input box, nor does adding an event listener).

In this case, you can iterate through the options which are selected, and give them the `selected` *attribute*, which will be reflected in the HTML markup (and therefore retrieved properly). The `selected` attribute will result in the option in question being selected on pageload:

```
for (const option of document.querySelectorAll('option:checked')) {
  option.setAttribute('selected', '')
}
mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('printcontent').innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. When I added your code, it shows me an error. Not sure why. I added `onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected','selected');"` code on the `select` tag and it worked fine. Thanks for your efforts. +1 for the same.

Comment: I tried it, it worked fine for me. What error did it result in for you?

Comment: It threw an error on the editor and the code line became red and asked me to correct the same to make it work. I use dreamweaver.

Comment: If your editor doesn't understand ES2015 syntax, you should strongly consider upgrading the editor - 2015 was an eternity ago in web development terms. To support obsolete browsers, the best strategy is to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, then use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile down to ES5 for production.